# Debug one out of many azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure functions app with multiple functions. I have installed the Azure Functions Core Tools to enable debugging. Is there a way to debug one function at a time. My local setup is pointing to the test environment queues, so all functions can be triggered, which can be confusing when trying to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an ideal solution, but you can temporary put `[Disable]` attribute on functions that you don't need.

It also supports more advanced scenarios like `[Disable("settingname")]` to enable/disable based on current setting value and
`[Disable(typeof(DisableProvider))]` to disable based on logic that you can define yourself.

I can imagine you could make a `DisableProvider` that would return just one function as enabled - the one you are trying to debug.

Comment: Maybe not ideal, but it works! Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction. I found an example of the use of the `[Disable]` attribute here: [Example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/MiscOperations/Functions.cs#L104).

Answer (score 0):

You can reference your Azure Function library from a console app.  You can then call functions that would normally be triggered by a timer from the console app. This allows for easy unit testing, and you don't have to remember to re-enable timed functions.